# How to find standard deviation when sample size changes in R

Tags: r, probability, standard-deviation

How do you find the standard deviation for tails in R, when the sample size changes from n=100 to n=50 when tossing a coin?

Answer (score 1):

The standard deviation of $X \sim\mathsf{Binom}(n,p)$ is $\sigma_X = \sqrt{np(1-p)}.$ So when $n$ is halved, the standard deviation is divided by$\sqrt{2}.$

For example, with $p=1/2,$ the SD decreases from $5$ to $3.535534$ when $n$ decreases from $100$ to $50.$

```
sqrt(100/4)
[1] 5
sqrt(50/4)
[1] 3.535534
```

A simulation in R, with a million iterations, accurate to two decimal places:

```
set.seed(2021)
sd(rbinom(10^6, 100, 1/2))
[1] 5.002196
sd(rbinom(10^6, 50, 1/2))
[1] 3.533623
```